# Error while adding new data from ReactJs web app. into a MongoDB database --

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux, mongoose-schema, nodemon

the question pretty much explains what I am experiencing in my code.

I'll post some of the relevant code from my backend as well as my front end react code where from I am sending my requests ->

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = 4000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const playerRoutes = express.Router();

let Player = require('./player.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/playerDB', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function () {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

playerRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    Player.find(function (err, todos) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(todos);
        }
    });
});


playerRoutes.route('/:id').get(function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Player.findById(id, function(err, todo) {
        res.json(todo);
    });
});

playerRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
    let player = new Player(req.body);
    player.save()
        .then(todo => {
            res.status(200).json({ 'player': 'player added successfully' });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new player failed');
        });
});


playerRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res) {
    Player.findById(req.params.id, function(err, todo) {
        if (!player)
            res.status(404).send('player data is not found');
        else
            player.player_name = req.body.player_name;
            player.player_description = req.body.player_description;
            player.player_position = req.body.player_position;
            player.player_age=req.body.player_age;
            player.player_club=req.body.player_club;
            player.player_=req.body.player_;
            player.player_isactive = req.body.player_isactive;
            player.player_completed = req.body.player_completed;

            player.save().then(player => {
                res.json('Player updated');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
            });
    });
});


app.use('/playerDB', playerRoutes);

//module.exports = mongoose.model('playerDB', playerDB);

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});
```

My model class player.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


let Player = new Schema({
    player_name: {
        type: String
    },
    player_description: {
        type: String
    },
    player_position: {
        type: String
    },
    player_age: {
        type: String
    },
    player_club: {
        type: String
    },
    player_: {
        type: String
    },
    player_isactive: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    player_completed: {
        type: Boolean
    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('player', Player);
```

Now after starting my backend by **nodemon server** and invoking the 2 exe files, mongo.exe and mongod.exe, I am sending a request to the backend to add a new record to my mongodb database. The relevant code for that is -->

create-player.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class CreatePlayers extends Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.onChangePlayerName = this.onChangePlayerName.bind(this);
        this.onChangePlayerDescription = this.onChangePlayerDescription.bind(this);
        this.onChangePlayerPosition = this.onChangePlayerPosition.bind(this);
        this.onChangePlayerAge = this.onChangePlayerAge.bind(this);
        this.onChangePlayerClub = this.onChangePlayerClub.bind(this);
        this.onChangePlayer_ = this.onChangePlayer_.bind(this);
        this.onChangePlayerIsActive = this.onChangePlayerIsActive.bind(this);
        this.onChangePlayerCompleted = this.onChangePlayerCompleted.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            player_name: '',
            player_description: '',
            player_position: '',
            player_age: '',
            player_club:'',
            player_: '',
            player_isactive: false,
            player_completed: false
        }
    }


    onChangePlayerName(e) {
        this.setState({
            player_name: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePlayerDescription(e) {
        this.setState({
            player_description: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePlayerPosition(e) {
        this.setState({
            player_position: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePlayerAge(e) {
        this.setState({
            player_age: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePlayerClub(e) {
        this.setState({
            player_club: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePlayer_(e) {
        this.setState({
            player_: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePlayerIsActive(e) {
        this.setState({
            player_isactive: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePlayerCompleted(e) {
        this.setState({
            player_completed: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const newPlayer = {
            player_name: this.state.player_name,
            player_description: this.state.player_description,
            player_position: this.state.player_position,
            player_age: this.state.player_age,
            player_club: this.state.player_club,
            player_: this.state.player_,
            player_isactive: this.state.player_isactive,
            player_completed: this.state.player_completed

        }

        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/playerDB/add', newPlayer)
            .then(res => console.log(res.data));

        this.setState({
            player_name: '',
            player_description: '',
            player_position: '',
            player_age: '',
            player_club:'',
            player_: '',
            player_isactive: false,
            player_completed: false
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                <h3 className="txt-blue" style={{marginLeft:15}}>Create New Player</h3>

                <form className="form-class" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Name: </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.player_name}
                            onChange={this.onChangePlayerName}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Player Description: </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.player_description}
                            onChange={this.onChangePlayerDescription}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Position: </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.player_position}
                            onChange={this.onChangePlayerPosition}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Age: </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.player_age}
                            onChange={this.onChangePlayerAge}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Club: </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.player_club}
                            onChange={this.onChangePlayerClub}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Player Status: </label>
                        <input type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            value={this.state.player_}
                            onChange={this.onChangePlayer_}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-check">
                        <input className="form-check-input"
                            type="radio"
                            name="isactive"
                            id="isactive"
                            value="Active"
                            checked={this.state.player_isactive === 'Active'}
                            onChange={this.onChangePlayerIsActive}
                        />
                        <label className="form-check-label">Active</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-check" style={{marginTop:20}}>
                        <input className="form-check-input"
                            type="radio"
                            name="completed"
                            id="completed"
                            value="Active"
                            checked={this.state.player_completed === 'Active'}
                            onChange={this.onChangePlayerCompleted}
                        />
                        <label className="form-check-label">Completed</label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group" style={{marginTop:20}}>
                        <input type="submit" value="Create Player" className="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Would seem pretty much straight forward. or so I would have thought. But I am getting the following error while saving

```
http://localhost:4000/playerDB/add 400 (Bad Request)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

I am not sure how to debug a MERN application, specifically the nodejs part of the backend. My experience with React and Mongo is now 1 week. Mostly exploring things only. Can you tell me which part of my code could have gone wrong? I want to know 2 things here ->
 1. error of my code
 2. way to debug this myself [I am using VS2017]

Need some fast help on this,

Comment: try to add HTTP Module. https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp

Comment: hi @Qui-GonJinn I'll try that, but I have a hunch that is not the issue. AT least logically thinking, it should not require, since I am already using axios to make the call. 'http' seems irrelevant here. anyway, let me try this,